# Is a random vector with spherically symmetric distribution and iid entries always Gaussian?

Tags: probability

Let $\mathbf{X} = (X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ be a random vector with spherically symmetric distribution.

Assuming that $X_i$ are also independent and identically distributed, must $\mathbf{X}$ always be Gaussian? Or are there also other nontrivial examples of such random vectors.

Comment: It's a Maxwell's Theorem (or Herschel-Maxwell's theorem). Actually, you don't need identically distributed assumption, it already follows that if $X=(X_1,...,X_n), n \ge 2$ is a nradom vector rotationally invariant with product distribution, then the entries are i.i.d gaussians.